# How do I whitelist an ip for a limited time?

Tags: centos, firewalld, ipset

I'm trying to create auto-whitelisting of IPs with a timeout based on certain events using firewalld and ipsets.

This is how far I got

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=whitelist --type=hash:ip --option=timeout=30
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-rich-rule='rule source ipset=whitelist accept'
firewall-cmd --ipset=whitelist --add-entry=AA.BB.CC.DD
```

But get this error message from the last command:

```
Error: IPSET_WITH_TIMEOUT: whitelist
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

I was indeed missing something obvious and discovered something not so obvious:

This is the chain of commands that will create an ipset with a timeout in firewalld

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=whitelist --type=hash:ip --option=timeout=30
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-source=ipset:whitelist
```

I was missing the --add-source bit (note that the rich rule isn't neccessary). But, trying to add an entry to the ipset through firewall-cmd still gives the same error as in the initial question. However one can use the native ipset command directly:

```
#ipset add whitelist AA.BB.CC.DD
#ipset list whitelist
Name: whitelist
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 timeout 30
Size in memory: 16592
References: 7
Members:
AA.BB.CC.DD timeout 22
```

This setup whitelist the given IP address for 30 seconds. Just what I needed.

The reason for all this is to be able to provide an automatic mechanism for giving access to a remote desktop service for users logging into our servers with ssh. The ipset add command is run from a syslog event handler that detects successful ssh logins and grabs the associated source ip the user is logging in from. The whitelist timeout limits the attack window to the remote vnc connection significantly. We have been using a similar setup on CentOS6 based on tcp-wrapper. Now we are moving on to CentOS7 and  using ipset timeouts removes the need for our own bookkeeping to close allowed ip-addresses after the timeout window has expired.